# Parsing whole project with semantic

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

I'm searching for a way to parse the whole directory with source code with semantic. Is this possible to do without explicitly opening each file in emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There's a thing called an EDE project in CEDET - where you can specify the list of files in a project file.  Semantic then does analysis of all of the files listed in the .ede project, and stored that in the database.

At that point, completion and intellisense works on all of those files.

Comment: So instead of opening each file the solution is to manually add each file to the list? Doesn't seem very helpful. The solution should be along the lines of M-x semantic-scan-every-file-reachable-from-this-folder RET /path/to/project/root RET

Comment: I'm not a big fan of EDE or CEDET, and I don't use these packages.  But I think it's a little better than you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I use [projman](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/projman.el) mode on top of EDE.  It aids in the creation of projects and provides convenient functions to find all source files and generate a global TAGS file.  I had tried CEDET on and off for the past couple years and had always come away disappointed until I discovered projman.